# Propagator for tensor product state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, propagator

So I understand, for example, the free particle propagator for a physical ket state in Hilbert space is evaluated by seeing how the unitary representation of time acts on the position kets etc...
Now, suppose I have two particles, where I am considering a physical ket state in the tensor product Hilbert space, what is the way to go about finding the two-particle state propagator given also they strongly interact with one another (so they are not free)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't make any simplifying assumptions, you'll just have to solve the Schrodinger equation.  You presumably know the two particle Hamiltonian, so you can solve for the propagator $U$ by writing the operator equation
$$i\hbar\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\hat U = \hat H\hat U$$
and then going from there, just like you would for a single particle (except that the operators $\hat H$ and $\hat U$ now act on two-particle states).

---

Example:  Two particles of mass $m$ in an external potential $\hat V_{\mathrm{ext}}$ with an interaction term $\hat V_{\mathrm{int}}$ would have a Hamiltonian of the form

$$\hat H  = \frac{\hat P_1^2}{2m}+\frac{\hat P_2^2}{2m}+\hat V_\mathrm{ext}(\hat X_1) + \hat V_{\mathrm{ext}}(\hat X_2) + \hat V_{\mathrm{int}}(\hat X_1,\hat X_2)$$

and a propagator formally given by
$$\hat U(t-t_0) = \exp\left[\frac{-i(t-t_0)}{\hbar}\hat H\right]$$

We could define $\hat H_i\equiv \frac{\hat P_i^2}{2m} + \hat V_{\mathrm{ext}}(\hat X_i)$, in which case the Hamiltonian would be

$$\hat H = \hat H_1 + \hat H_2 + \hat V_{\mathrm{int}}(\hat X_1,\hat X_2)$$

If $\hat V_\mathrm{int}$ were small, then we could treat it as a perturbation; in this case, we would start by solving the single-particle Schrodinger equations and then calculating successively smaller corrections.  If not, then there's no general recipe for solving such a problem.  You can search for eigenvalues and eigenstates like you would with any other operator, it's just that your differential equations will involve two position variables rather than one.

Comment: Where does that equality come from? 
Also, could you give me an example of two particle state with a kinetic term, a common potential and an interacting potential? I don’t understand how to formulate all this when particles are interacting.

Comment: @TheDawg That's the Schrodinger equation for the propagator, obtained by letting $|\psi(t)\rangle = U(t-t_0)|\psi_0\rangle$. I've updated my answer with an example "template" Hamiltonian for two interacting particles in an external potential.

Comment: So formally speaking, the individual hamiltonians act on their corresponding hilbert space through the tensor product of the two particle state, how does the interacting term interact in terms of its mapping from tensor Hilbert space to tensor Hilbert space?

Comment: @TheDawg Formally, we should write $\hat H = \hat H_1 \otimes \mathbb 1 + \mathbb 1 \otimes \hat H_2 + \hat V$.  The first two operators act on one factor of the tensor product state while leaving the other alone, but the third operator cannot be separated in that way.  Other than that I'm not sure what you're asking; it's an operator which eats a tensor product state and spits out another tensor product state.  If you want to be more specific, you need a concrete example.

Comment: I agree with the expression, so for example, the coulomb interaction between two particles, how does that act on the tensor space?

Comment: @TheDawg $\hat V_{\mathrm{Coulomb}} \psi(x_1,x_2) = \frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0|x_1-x_2|} \psi(x_1,x_2)$, assuming we're working in 3D space.

Comment: Sure, but in terms of the operator acting on the state vector, what does it means for 1. Reciprocal of an operator. 2. Magnitude of an operator acting on a state vector.

Comment: @TheDawg I don't know what you mean, I'm afraid.  The $x_i$'s I have written are numbers - I'm defining the operator by its action in the $|x_1,x_2\rangle$ basis.  This is no different from the SHO potential for a single particle, $\hat V \psi(x) = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2 \psi(x)$.

Comment: Ok, so I believe your expression there is what you get after projecting this mapped tensor state onto the position tensor base. If true, what is the interacting potential’s representation on a tensor Hilbert state without talking about position bases. What if I wanted in terms of momentum tensor base etc...

Comment: @TheDawg Then you take the expression I wrote and apply a change of basis by inserting copies of the identity operator $\int dp_1 dp_2 |p_1,p_2\rangle\langle p_1,p_2|$, just like you do in single particle quantum mechanics.  This will amount to taking the Fourier transform of the potential in the case of the momentum basis.

Comment: You would insert the identity operator between the interacting Hamiltonian, the bra tensor position bases and the tensor Hilbert state ? Sorry I can’t write this all down, I’m on my phone right now. If what I’m saying is correct, could you just write what I have stated just to see if we are clear and there is no misconstruing.

Comment: The potential in the position basis is $\hat V  = \int dx_1 dx_2 \  |x_1,x_2\rangle \frac{q_1 q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 |x_1-x_2|} \langle x_1,x_2|$.  Expressing it in the momentum basis would involve inserting an identity operator $\int dp_1 dp_2 \ |p_1,p_2\rangle\langle p_1,p_2|$ at the beginning and an identity operator $\int dp_1' dp_2' \ |p_1',p_2'\rangle\langle p_1',p_2'|$ at the end - $\hat V = \mathbf 1  \cdot \hat V \cdot \mathbf 1$.

Comment: Great ok, so to get the propagator in position bases, I would exponentiate, then take first order terms in the potential and interacting potential and full term in momentum, sandwich this in between the tensor position bras and kets and see how it all plays out? Problem is while I can precisely find for the momentum squared operator by adding momentum identity operators, would I have to perform multiple integrals for the potential operators? If confused, please refer to page 18-19 of this https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/53706

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119056/discussion-between-j-murray-and-thedawg).